# How do I import bootstrap via webpack?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack

I am now constructing a Typescript webapp by using webpack.
Some modules can be imported by being written in webpack.config.js file like below.
But how many times I tried, bootstrap module won't be imported into my app.

How should I do ?

here is a part of my webpack.config.js

```
plugins: [
    new webpack.ResolverPlugin(
        new webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin('.bower.json', ['main'])
    ),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery',
        _: 'lodash',
        Vue: 'vue'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin()
],
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I finally and fortunately have found an answer.

The answer is to use `BowerWebpackplugin` instead of `webpack.ResolverPlugin.DirectoryDescriptionFilePlugin`

```
plugins: [
    new BowerWebpackPlugin({
        modulesDirectories: ['bower_components'],
        manifestFiles: ['bower.json', 'package.json'],
        includes: [/.*\.js/],
        excludes: [/.*\.less/],
        searchResolveModulesDirectories: true
    }),
    new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        jQuery: 'jquery',
        $: 'jquery',
        jquery: 'jquery',
        _: 'lodash',
        Vue: 'vue'
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.DedupePlugin(),
    new webpack.optimize.AggressiveMergingPlugin()
],
module: {
    loaders: [
        { test: /\.ts$/, loader: 'ts-loader' }
    ]
}
```